# Deadlock on AcquireNextFrame() and ReleaseFrame() randomly in Desktop Duplication API

Tags: directx, video-capture, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx, desktop-duplication

I'm attempting to write an application for recording the Windows desktop to a video file. I'm making use of the desktop duplication API and the Media Foundation API. More specifically I'm using the `SinkWriter` class from Media Foundation. I'm consuming `Texture2D` objects from the Desktop Duplication API and passing them to the `SinkWriter`, which makes for a nicely hardware accelerated pipeline. I'm also using C# with `SharpDX`.

The entire project works very well for the most part. it runs flawlessly on my Surface Pro, capturing fairly consistent fps video without issue.

The trouble has been on other hardware. Specifically I've tested I've tested this on an AMD Ryzen with a discrete Nvidia GPU. This also works fairly well.. except after recording the desktop for usually between 8 and 20 seconds, the program will get locked up on either `outputDuplication.ReleaseFrame()` or `outputDuplication.AcquireNextFrame()`. It doesn't crash, it just locks up so I'm unsure how to figure out what's happening. What I do know for sure is it has something to do with passing the desktop texture to the `sinkWriter.WriteSample()` function. If I remove this line, and keep all else the same, as in continue to create the `MediaBuffers` and `MediaSamples` as usual, associate them with my desktop texture, but simply don't pass the sample to the `WriteSample` method, then the application can happily "record" seemingly indefinitely.

I've checked for every potential mistake I can think of. I made sure all objects are disposed when they should be. There are no memory leaks that I can see. The code uses the `SetAllocator()` method on the `MediaSample`, thus the textures I pass to the `SinkWriter` are recycled. From what I can tell, this all works correctly.

I suspect there's something basic I'm not understanding here. It feels like there's some mistake I've made with managing the unmanaged resources behind `SharpDX` correctly, but I really don't know where to start to look. Any pointers would be massively appreciated at this point.

Here's the main capture code. This isn't everything, but most of it. I suspect the issue is somewhere in here.

```
static void WriteFrame(SinkWriter sinkWriter, int steamIndex, long time, long duration, int width, int height, Texture2D texture, TextureAllocator textureAllocator)
{
    MediaBuffer textureBuffer;
    MediaFactory.CreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(texture.GetType().GUID, texture, 0, false, out textureBuffer);
    using (var buffer2d = textureBuffer.QueryInterface<Buffer2D>())
    {
        textureBuffer.CurrentLength = buffer2d.ContiguousLength;
    }

    using (var sample = MediaFactory.CreateVideoSampleFromSurface(null))
    {
        sample.SampleTime = time;
        sample.SampleDuration = duration;
        sample.AddBuffer(textureBuffer);
        using(var trackedSample = sample.QueryInterface<TrackedSample>())
        {
            trackedSample.SetAllocator(textureAllocator, null);
        }
        sinkWriter.WriteSample(steamIndex, sample);
    }
    textureBuffer.Dispose();
}


void captureAction()
{
    MediaManager.Startup(true);

    int streamIndex = 0;

    var whichOutputDevice = 0;
    var whichAdapter = 0;
    using (var factory = new Factory1())
    {

        using (var adapter = factory.GetAdapter1(whichAdapter))
        {
            using (var mDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(adapter))
            {
                using (var dXGIDeviceManager = new DXGIDeviceManager())
                {
                    dXGIDeviceManager.ResetDevice(mDevice);
                    using (var output = adapter.GetOutput(whichOutputDevice))
                    {
                        using (var output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>())
                        {
                            var mOutputDesc = output.Description;
                            var mTextureDesc = new Texture2DDescription()
                            {
                                CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
                                BindFlags = BindFlags.None,
                                Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                                Width = mOutputDesc.DesktopBounds.Right - mOutputDesc.DesktopBounds.Left,
                                Height = mOutputDesc.DesktopBounds.Bottom - mOutputDesc.DesktopBounds.Top,
                                OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.None,
                                MipLevels = 1,
                                ArraySize = 1,
                                SampleDescription = { Count = 1, Quality = 0 },
                                Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging
                            };
                            using (var outputDuplication = output1.DuplicateOutput(mDevice))
                            {
                                using (var sinkWriter = InitialiseSinkWriter(path, out streamIndex, mTextureDesc.Width, mTextureDesc.Height, frameRate, mDevice, dXGIDeviceManager, preferHardwareAcceleration))
                                {
                                    using (var rgbToNv12 = new RGBToNV12ConverterD3D11(mDevice, mDevice.ImmediateContext, mTextureDesc.Width, mTextureDesc.Height))
                                    {
                                        var newDesc = mTextureDesc;
                                        if (forceNV12)
                                            newDesc.Format = Format.NV12;
                                        newDesc.BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget;
                                        newDesc.Usage = ResourceUsage.Default;
                                        newDesc.CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None;
                                        var textureAllocator = new TextureAllocator(mDevice, newDesc);
                                        {

                                            var timeStart = 0L;
                                            var frameCount = 0;

                                            var totalAFMilliseconds = 0.0;
                                            var lastTimeStamp = 0L;
                                            var frameAquired = false;
                                            for (int i = 0; !stopCapture; i++)
                                            {
                                                var sleepAmount = Math.Max(0, (1000 / frameRate) / 2);
                                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepAmount);
                                                frameCount++;
                                                SharpDX.DXGI.Resource desktopResource = null;
                                                var frameInfo_ = new OutputDuplicateFrameInformation();
                                                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                                                sw.Start();

                                                var outputLoopCount = 0;
                                                if (outputDuplication != null)
                                                {//desktop duplication
                                                    int aquireFrameLoopCount = 0;
                                                    while (frameInfo_.LastPresentTime == 0)
                                                    {
                                                        aquireFrameLoopCount++;
                                                        if (aquireFrameLoopCount > 1)
                                                        {
                                                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                                                        }
                                                        if (frameAquired)
                                                            try
                                                            {
                                                                outputDuplication.ReleaseFrame();
                                                                frameAquired = false;
                                                            }
                                                            catch (Exception e)
                                                            {
                                                            }
                                                        try
                                                        {
                                                            outputDuplication.AcquireNextFrame(500, out frameInfo_, out desktopResource);
                                                            frameAquired = true;
                                                        }
                                                        catch (Exception e)
                                                        {
                                                        }
                                                        outputLoopCount++;
                                                    }
                                                    Debug.Assert(frameInfo_.LastPresentTime != 0);
                                                    Debug.Assert(frameInfo_.AccumulatedFrames != 0);
                                                }
                                                sw.Stop();
                                                var frameCaptureTime = frameCount * TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / frameRate).Ticks;
                                                frameCaptureTime = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
                                                var aqTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)sw.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency);
                                                totalAFMilliseconds += aqTime.TotalMilliseconds;

                                                if (desktopResource != null)
                                                    using (var desktopTexture = desktopResource?.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
                                                    {
                                                        Texture2D desktopTextureCopy = null;
                                                        try
                                                        {
                                                            desktopTextureCopy = textureAllocator.AllocateTexture();
                                                        }
                                                        catch (SharpDX.SharpDXException e)
                                                        {
                                                            var result = mDevice.DeviceRemovedReason;
                                                            result.CheckError();
                                                            throw e;
                                                        }
                                                        if (outputDuplication != null)
                                                            rgbToNv12.ConvertRGBToNV12(desktopTexture, desktopTextureCopy);

                                                        if (frameCount == 2)
                                                            timeStart = lastTimeStamp;
                                                        Console.WriteLine("Writing frame {0}", TimeSpan.FromTicks(frameCaptureTime - lastTimeStamp).ToString());

                                                        if (frameCount > 0)
                                                        {
                                                            var frameDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / frameRate).Ticks;
                                                            var time = (frameCount - 2) * frameDuration;
                                                            WriteFrame(sinkWriter, streamIndex, lastTimeStamp - timeStart, frameCaptureTime - lastTimeStamp, desktopTextureCopy.Description.Width, desktopTextureCopy.Description.Height, desktopTextureCopy, textureAllocator);

                                                            Console.WriteLine("frame written");
                                                        }
                                                        desktopTextureCopy.Dispose();
                                                    }
                                                lastTimeStamp = frameCaptureTime;
                                                CaptureTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(lastTimeStamp - timeStart);

                                                if (CaptureFramesChanged != null)
                                                {
                                                    CaptureFramesChanged.Invoke(null, new EventArgs());
                                                }

                                                Console.WriteLine("end of loop");
                                            }
                                            stopCapture = false;
                                            Console.WriteLine("Total AquireFrame time: {0}", totalAFMilliseconds / (300 * (1000 / frameRate)));
                                            Console.WriteLine("Begining finalise");
                                            sinkWriter.Finalize();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MediaManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How you set DirectX11 device handler to the video encoder? In Surface Pro there is ONE GPU with hardware accelerated H264 encoder - as a result, there is not problem with DirectX11 device handler - GPU and HA H264 share the same video memory. In your test system `AMD Ryzen with a discrete Nvidia GPU` you can have situation: video memory in NVIDIA, but HA H264 in Ryzen!?!

Comment: @EvgenyPereguda The `dXGIDeviceManager` is set to use the same device as is used to present the desktop. This device is passed to the `SinkWriter`. The `SinkWriter` automatically chooses the best hardware encoder to use, which in this case is the NVidia (NVEnc) one.

Comment: The problem with NVidia GPUs is that not all of them have NVEnc - some models have locked NVEnc - [GeForce 840m 4gb NVENC + SHADOWPLAY](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/36hryu/geforce_840m_4gb_nvenc_shadowplay/)

Comment: @EvgenyPereguda Not the GPU I'm using though, as it records perfectly for 8-20 seconds or so. If I end the recording before it freezes up, it produces a beautiful h.264 mp4 video saved to my file system. The only issue is the it eventually randomly locks up if I record for long enough as described.

Comment: How about [BeginWriting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-imfsinkwriter-beginwriting)?  I cannot find this method in your code, but `You must call BeginWriting before calling IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample`!?!

Comment: @EvgenyPereguda Yes, BeginWriting is indeed called inside the `InitialiseSinkWriter()` function, which I did not add in the code I posted. The issue seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Seems it was some multithreading issue and was fixed by adding these lines:

```
using(var multiThread = mDevice.QueryInterface<Multithread>())
{
    multiThread.SetMultithreadProtected(true);
}
```

Right after the creating the device.